# Wrap flutter elements vertically

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am displaying a list of checkboxes in two columns, using the Wrap widget like so:

```
Wrap(
                direction: Axis.horizontal,
                children: _propertyTypes.map((propertyType) {
                  var halfWidth = (getWidth(context) - AppPadding.standard) / 2;

                  return SizedBox(
                    width: halfWidth,
                    child: CustomCheckbox(
                      key: UniqueKey(),
                      label: propertyType.toDescription(),
                      labelFontSize: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium!.fontSize!,
                      isChecked: criteria.propertyTypeIds!.contains(propertyTypeEnumMap[propertyType]),
                      borderColor: AppColor.colorBlue500,
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
```

This displays the first element in row 1 / column 1, the second element in row 1 / column 2, the third element in row 2 / column 1, and so on.

[image]

What I want is to display the elements vertically in column 1 and then vertically in column 2. For example if there are 10 elements, the first 5 would display in column 1 from top down then the last 5 would display in column 2 from top down. I can't find a way to do this using the Wrap widget, is there another approach that would achieve the desired result?

Comment: You can change wrap direction but then you need to define a height for that Wrap so items can be placed inside the second column as well, so it's not a good solution. I would recommend taking a look at GridView widget, this widget allows you to specify the number of widgets on each axis and define the proper grid layout.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
SizedBox(
height: 300, /// <=== height as per your requirement
child: Wrap(
  direction: Axis.vertical,/// <=== change here
  children: _propertyTypes.map((propertyType) {
    var halfWidth = (getWidth(context) - AppPadding.standard) / 2;

    return SizedBox(
      width: halfWidth,
      child: CustomCheckbox(
        key: UniqueKey(),
        label: propertyType.toDescription(),
        labelFontSize: Theme
            .of(context)
            .textTheme
            .bodyMedium!
            .fontSize!,
        isChecked: criteria.propertyTypeIds!.contains(propertyTypeEnumMap[propertyType]),
        borderColor: AppColor.colorBlue500,
      ),
    );
  }).toList(),
),
```

)